# Why user_save overrides user picture?

Tags: users

I have a user profile form. If a user selects a picture, it's uploaded and shows on user profile but If user just updates other details and leaves the picture the same the user_save overrides the user picture and then there is no user picture. 
My code is like this.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name']['profile_image']) && isset($_FILES['files']['name']['profile_image']) && ($_FILES['files']['size']['profile_image'] != 0)) {

        $filepath = 'public://pictures/';
        $file = file_save_upload('profile_image', $validators, $filepath);
        $file->status = 1;
        file_save($file);
        if(isset($file) && !empty($file) && !is_null($file)) {
            $loaded_user->picture = $file;
        }

    }
user_save
```

Comment: Can you post your whole form code, not just this part? Without seeing the rest of the code I would assume you are not setting the previously saved value as the default value for the picture field.

Comment: Thank you rooby for your comment. This is the section where I add the file.                                                                        $form['profile']['profile-share']['upload-photo']['upload-pic']['upload'] = array(
     '#name' => 'files[profile_image]',
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => 'profilbild',
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#size' => 30,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id'=> 'upload',
        ),

    );

Comment: You're right, I'm not setting the previously set value as a default value. Where can I set it because the #default_value property is not used by file?

Comment: Can you post the whole code for your form in your original post by editing it, then it will be easier to give a correct answer. - You can change field names etc. if they are sensitive information.

Comment: The whole form is too big to be posted here but If you could tell me how to set a default value for the file then may be I'll fix it.

Comment: Even just the part where you define the file field in question would help, but I will make some assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are not setting you default_value for the file field and that you are using a managed_file field.

The default value should be the fid of the file that has been uploaded before.

Something like this:

```
$form['profile_image'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Profile picture'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#description' => t('Upload a photo for your profile.'),
  '#default_value' => $previously_uploaded_file->fid,
);
```

In your case I'm not exactly sure where the $previously_uploaded_file->fid will come from, but I assume it will be in your form or form state or else you will have to get it from the database or something.

If you are using a regular file field instead of a managed_file file field I don't believe you can set a default value.

In that case you have to make sure that when you do the user save that you are not overwriting the file with an empty value.

Comment: Thank again rooby, it's type is file. I can get the fid from DB.

Comment: In that case I don't believe that you can use default value. I have added some more info to the answer.

Comment: +1 for your time. I had already checked the default value for type file. I couldn't solve it, will ask some senior developer in my company to help me. Thank you again.

Comment: Your use case may be different but I would have thought a user picture would be better as a managed_file?